# What do you use to test the handheld css on your website?

Tags: html, css, testing, media, handheld

I've been adding css support for **handheld** to my website but haven't been able to find a good tool for testing.

I tried using the webdeveloper plugin for Firefox but it doesn't work for me. Maybe that is because all my css is in the html and not a seperate css file.

Are there any other testing tools available aside from going out and buying a handheld device?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With a bit of hunting I found what I was looking for, thanks for the leads guys.

Opera will display the **handheld** css if you select "Small Screen" from the View menu.

Comment: You could also just test screen-based css in IE6 on windows, but I wouldn't recommend it...

Comment: Why on earth would someone downvote this when I FOUND what I was looking for, call me confused.

Comment: I don't see the "Small Screen" option in the latest (10.53) version of Opera.  Perhaps it has been removed.

Comment: @John The option has moved. Press Shift+F11 or look under Page > Developer Tools > Layout > Mobile View.

Comment: @mercator: Thanks, but this still doesn't work for me. I see View -> Developer Tools, but no Layout under that.  And Shift+F11 doesn't do anything.

Comment: @John: hmmm, maybe you need the [Debug menu](http://dragonfly.opera.com/app/debugmenu/DebugMenu.ini) in that case. Also see here: http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if it's a good idea to resurrect the old question, but I hope somebody finds it :)

There's a simple way to test handheld css with with [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/):

```
    @media handheld, screen and (max-width: 500px) { /* your css */ }
```

After that you can  test on  browsers that implement media queries by resizing the window to less than 500px.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Visual Studio, there should be device emulators which let you test mobile IE, or they can be found standalone on Microsoft's site.  [Here are some for WM 5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=C62D54A5-183A-4A1E-A7E2-CC500ED1F19A&displaylang=en).  There is an [OpenWave simulator](http://developer.openwave.com/dvl/tools_and_sdk/phone_simulator/) available to test that browser.  [Blackberry simulators](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/browserdev/devtoolsdownloads.jsp) are available as well, to test the Blackberry browser.  You can (kind of) test iPhone support with Safari, although you can't verify the viewport meta-tag.  There's an [Opera Mini simulator](http://www.operamini.com/demo/) here.

Also, get your CSS out of your HTML :)

Comment: My CSS is embeded since it is customized based on the users preferences ( they can customize the default font size / colors etc ). I guess I should split out the part that is static. It's on my to-do list.

Comment: You can also serve it dynamically from your server.  Have a server-side process (php script, whatever) handle the request for customUser.css and write it based on their preferences.  This way it can still be cached by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I found out that switching media types in development environment works best for me.

For example if you are testing "handheld" css then just add media type "screen" to media atrib and 
comment out your default css.

After this step is complete, you normally would want to test in on real handheld device.

```
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="screen.css" /> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen,handheld" href="handheld.css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

For testing the iPhone, you can get the iPhone SDK [here](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/program/download.html)
But you need OS X / Apple computer  for it to run the official way.

Not official/hacks:

- There are ways to get OS X running on standart PC hardware like [here](http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).
- Or get the SDK running in Linux / vmware described [here](http://www.phranker.com/2008/01/update-iphone-application-development/).

Happy Hacking!

Huibert Gill

Answer (score 0):

Most smartphones like the iPhone and some Android devices don't recognize the `handheld.css`. They took the `mediatype="screen"` so you need to include this [short snippet of JavaScript](http://www.smashingninja.com/webdesign/optimize-website-for-mobile-devices/).