# Is there a way to force IE or FF into a handheld mode for testing "@media handheld" stylesheets?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, testing, handheld

Is there a way to force IE or FF into a handheld mode for testing "@media handheld" stylesheets?

Or, do I have to publish the pages and test with my Blackberry?

I'd prefer to test this without pushing the application to the live server as the application is already in use.

Any ideas for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some help on this question:
[What do you use to test the handheld css on your website?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259330/what-do-you-use-to-test-the-handheld-css-on-your-website)

Comment: Thanks!  Now, why couldn't I find that page when I searched?

Comment: The magic of Google search, "site:stackoverflow.com firefox handheld"

Comment: Opera is one of the top browsers in mobile market, so it even makes more sense than testing in Firefox.

Comment: Sure, but it is something that I'd have to install.  I have too many browsers already!

Answer (score 5):

Web Developer Toolbar for FF lets you to test webpages media=handheld

Comment: It took me a while to find, so for anyone else who is bad at finding things quickly, this feature is at: CSS > Display CSS by Media Type > Handheld

Answer (score 3):

There's a simple way with [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/):

```
@media handheld, screen and (max-width: 500px) { /* your css */ }
```

This will make browsers that implement media queries use your handheld css when you resize the window to less than 500px.

Answer (score 0):

I've found Blackberry browser to be so utterly broken, that testing in Firefox or even IE doesn't make sense. Netscape 4 seems like closest approximation.

If you want achieve decent experience on BB, then you have to get a BB simulator. It's available for free from RIM website (you need to click through a few forms).

If you just want to test under *a* mobile browser, than try [Opera Mini simlator on-line](http://operamini.com/demo) or [desktop Opera in Small Screen view](http://www.opera.com/download/index.dml?custom=yes) (get version 7.6 or 8.0 from archives if you want exactly the same engine as used today on smartphones).

Or add `html {max-width:240px}` to your styles and for testing serve them with `media=screen` rather than `handheld`.